# How to get POST raw data on PHP using $_SERVER

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, query-string

I have a dynamic page using on-page-filter i change the data on the page using AJAX response, my question is how can i get from POST raw data when on the URL is not written..

my link on the page is similar like this "example.com/default/list_data"

and on my AJAX I created the query string like this

```
function create_qs() {
var qs = '?1=1';
$('.fltlist').each(function (index, item) {
    var val = ($(item).hasClass('active')) ? 'Y' : 'N';
    qs += '&' + $(item).attr('f') + '=' + val;
});
qs += '&from=' + $('#startdate').val();
qs += '&to=' + $('#enddate').val();
qs += '&sort=' + $('#sort_sppt_ticket').val();
qs += '&search=' + $('#search').val();
qs += '&developer=' + $('#fltlistdev').val();
return qs;
}
```

but on the URL bar it didn't show anything (because the post) I'm using AJAX POST..

i need the raw data and store on the PHP array (maybe in global variable) to pass the raw data to another page..

any help?

Comment: Query params will be in $_GET obviously. It doesn't matter which method you used. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

`$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");`